# Writing information to excel columns with loops

Tags: c#, excel, loops

I am trying to write this a set of data into a single column in excel with using a loop. I cant figure out why it currently does not write to different cells.

I have tried running this code and it shows up with just one of the values in the first cell that it should write in

```
foreach (Element e in wirelist)
{
    Excel.Worksheet sheet = 
    (Excel.Worksheet)workbook.Worksheets.get_Item("Wires (Exported)");
    int i = 3;
    int j = 1;

    ((Excel.Range)sheet.Cells[i, j]).Value = e.Id;
    i = i +  1;
}
```

It should print out a list of ID numbers in separate cells in the column.
Questions let me know!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your issue is that you keep getting the Excel sheet and resetting i and j within the loop. Try this:

```
       Excel.Worksheet sheet = (Excel.Worksheet)workbook.Worksheets.get_Item("Wires (Exported)");
       int i = 3;
       int j = 1;

       foreach (Element e in wirelist)
       {  
            ((Excel.Range)sheet.Cells[i, j]).Value = e.Id;
            i = i +  1;
       }
```

Comment: Thank you! I really cant believe overlooked that hahahah.